# Dragon dictation mouse clicks

Tags: click, applescript, mouse, dictation

I use a speech to text program called Dragon Dictation. I can use it for mouse clicks, but I have to say the word "mouse click" or "mouse triple click" which becomes very annoying after a while, I would like to just say click or triple.

The program allows AppleScript code to customize our commands, but I cannot figure out how to do mouse clicks?

Answer (score 1):

You can install a utility like: https://github.com/BlueM/cliclick

then call it from your AppleScript like:

```
do shell script "/usr/local/bin/cliclick c:+0,+0"
```

Also, if you want tons more voice control of a Mac check out this product: http://voicecode.io (disclaimer: this is a product I am working on)